# Javascript IF blocks get skipped

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm using this code to validate a form:

```
        if (isEmpty(email)) {
            alert("1");
            return false;
        }
        else if (!isEmail(email)) {
            alert("2");
            return false;
        }

        if (isEmpty(name)) {
            alert("3");
            return false;
        }

        if (isEmpty(age)) {
            alert("4");
            return false;
        }
        else if (!isAge(age)) {
            alert("5");
            return false;
        }

        if (isEmpty(city)) {
            alert("6");
            return false;

        }

        if (isEmpty(comments)) {
            alert("7");
            return false;
        }
```

When hitting the "Submit" button, if the first two conditions do work(The ones that check if the email var is empty or not in email address format) - meaning that if I leave the email input empty or not in an email address format I get the alert (1 or 2).

The problem is that the rest of the validations get skipped and it doesn't matter if I leave another input empty or not in format.

Also, if I take the first IF block:

```
 if (isEmpty(email)) {
            alert("1");
            return false;
        }
        else if (!isEmail(email)) {
            alert("2");
            return false;
        }
```

And move it to the end of the validation block, everything works just fine.

I'm guessing I have a wrong syntax somewhere but I spent 2 hours looking and just couldn't find it.

P.S.

here are the two validation functions I'm using:

```
function isEmpty(field) {
        if ((field == null || field == "")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


function isEmail(field) {
        var atpos = field.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = field.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `return` exits the function.

Comment: Please show the defintion of your "isEmail" function.

Comment: I don't see a problem in the code, as long as you understand that it only alerts on the first field that fails validation, not all of them.

Comment: Can you post a live demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? That will help see what the problem is.

Comment: have you implemented these functions isEmail and isAge?? if yes can you post them?

Comment: I've added the two extra functions to my question.

Thank you all for helping! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `x.length` in the isEmail function, but `x` is not defined.

Comment: Thank you Roland.

You saved the day.

Answer (score 2):

the return statement exits the function to get all the validations run

1. keep all the validations in if else if blocks and keep on using return false every time.
   or
2. set a variable to false whenever condition fails and then return the value. as j00lz said.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
return false;
```

ends the function and stops the rest of the code being executed.

Instead set a variable:

```
result="false";
```

and at the end of the function add

```
return result;
```

Comment: But if the email validates OK, it should perform the other validations. I think that's what he's saying doesn't happen.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.

As Barmar said, the problem is that when the email input gets validated, the function still breaks and the rest of the validations don't execute.

Comment: All the if statements will be run until you call a return

http://jsfiddle.net/SWjK6/

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you change it to this:

```
    if (isEmpty(email)) {
        alert("1");
        return false;
    }
    else if (!isEmail(email)) {
        alert("2");
        return false;
    }
    else if (isEmpty(name)) {
        alert("3");
        return false;
    }
    else if (isEmpty(age)) {
        alert("4");
        return false;
    }
    else if (!isAge(age)) {
        alert("5");
        return false;
    }
    else if (isEmpty(city)) {
        alert("6");
        return false;
    }
    else if (isEmpty(comments)) {
        alert("7");
        return false;
    }
```

I'm just curious as to what happens if you make the whole thing one big if statement rather than breaking it up into parts, considering it's not going to change the validation process.

**P.S.**

I'm not sure if you realize or not, but with the way you have it set up, once one of the first if statements comes back false, returning false with in that if statement will end the whole method you're working in, meaning it won't run any other parts of it. So if you're shooting for displaying an alert for each and every empty input, etc, it won't happen this way.

Comment: I tried your code, it still skips everything but the email validation.

Thanks for the angle tho :)

Comment: And you're sure there's not something going wrong within your isEmai() function? Because if it keeps breaking after the second block of the if statement, my money's on a problem in there some where.